# I am looking for a linux distrution that still supports fvwm2 windowmanager

Tags: linux, desktop, distribution-choice

I am looking to build a desktop with servers.   Debian, Ubuntu redhat....    I want to avoid snaps if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Debian, with:

```
sudo apt-get install fvwm
```

you will get the [latest stable frozen version](https://www.fvwm.org/) (2.7.0). See more info [here](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/fvwm).

Also Ubuntu [has it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/fvwm), and so does Fedora (up to at least version 38).